# A case that exhibits all the possible conditions a subject can suffer from?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

We have this Hungarian phrase "Állatorvosi ló", which literally translates to "Veterinarian horse".

It [originated in 19th century Hungarian literature](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=hu&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhu.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25C3%2581llatorvosi_l%25C3%25B3), when someone created an illustration of a horse that exhibited all the possible external and internal sicknesses a horse can have.

Nowadays it is used to describe all the possible (negative) conditions something can have.

In our concrete case, we're doing software testing for a CAT (Computer Aided Translation) software that has a QA module; and we're going to build a special project (the 'vetenarian horse') that exhibits all the possible errors the QA module can throw at us.

What would be an idiomatic word or phrase to express that?

Comment: In some computer circles a related term is "Christmas Tree", as in "lit up like a Christmas Tree". cf: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/Christmas-tree-packet.html Don't know of a medical term, though.

Comment: @AlexFeinman That sounds like an answer :) I don't think the OP is particular about a medical equivalent. An _autopsy_ or a _vivisection_ sounds a little too macabre in any event.

Comment: @KTamas, I think you would want the term "veterinarian's horse" or "veterinarian horse" or maybe "veterinary horse."

Comment: @coleopterist yeah, not particular about the medical part.

Comment: @AlexFeinman Christmas Tree does sound promising although I can't help to wonder if there is an even better expression for it.

Comment: It's a humbug. (http://board.jokeroo.com/funny-jokes/78828-humbug-anecdotal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly commonplace, but OP's QA module could be called a...

> [polypathological](http://journals.ohiolink.edu/ejc/search.cgi?q=keywords%3a%22Polypathological%20patient%22) test case *- having multiple chronic aliments*

Personally though, I think a little dry humour wouldn't go amiss here. I'd call it a...

> [basket case](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/basket+case) *- in a completely hopeless or useless condition*

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions, in the end, basket case sounds the best.

Comment: @KTamas: You might want to call yours the [definitive basket case](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22definitive+basket+case%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for the QA. Although in my experience, once you get beyond a certain level of complexity on the *input* side, it becomes impractical to set up tests for every feasible combination that might throw the software. Effectively, there's no such thing as a "definitive" test suite for anything beyond the trivial.

Answer (score 3):

"Case study" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/case+study
"Before they lost their independence, [the two companies] were case studies in unsuccessful long-term planning" (T. Boone Pickens, Jr.)"
So as showing all the symptoms of unsuccessful long-term planning.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the terms mentioned in comments ([humbug](http://board.jokeroo.com/funny-jokes/78828-humbug-anecdotal.html) and [Christmas tree](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/Christmas-tree-packet.html)), consider  *[poster child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poster_child)*; which literally is “a child afflicted by some disease or deformity whose picture is used on posters or other media as part of a campaign to raise money or enlist volunteers for a cause or organization” but figuratively is often used to mean an outstanding example of one problem or another.  An example from the wikipedia article:

> The Oakland County Intermediate School District (near Detroit) was cited as “the poster child for fiscal irresponsibility.”

That article links to *epitome* and *[archetype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archetype)* articles.  You might also refer to your horse as an *archetypal* or *[archetypical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/archetypical)* problem.  Also, unless you have already otherwise dedicated the term, you might call the problem a *[quintessence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quintessence)*, “A thing that is the most perfect example of its type; the most perfect embodiment of something”.  These latter terms are obvious once explained but perhaps not self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it said of people who exhibit significantly annoying behavior that they are or suffers from *MMPD*—"Minnesota Multiphasic Personality Disorder", an expression formed from the famous Minnesota Multiphasic Personality Inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The word [omnishambles](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omnishambles) has recently become popular in British politics.

Comment: I *hate* that word! Currently being flogged to death by Labour politicians trying to give the impression that they have their finger on the nation's "linguistic pulse" (and that they watch *The Thick of It* just like "ordinary" voters). Roll on the day when Mr Speaker rules that it's "unparliamentary language".